# if I turn on VPN, then type a password for LAN shared folder access, will the password be exposed?

Tags: security

I am not sure whether what I typed for the local network username and password would be sent to the VPN and out to the internet as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most VPNs use encryption, which would protect the username and password *while they are going from your computer through the VPN to the VPN server*.  However, most VPNs don't terminate at the target machine, only the target network.  Once the data hits the target network, it will be decrypted and sent to the server you are targeting just the same as if you were plugged into the destination LAN directly, which *could* be in the clear on that network. At that point, it depends on what kind of authentication you're doing.  Most modern file systems do encryption for all password access to file shares, so that should be safe too.

So, in short, it depends on your VPN's type and settings and the type of folder share you're connecting to.

In Windows, if you go to the VPN connection properties, there is an option to require encryption, which is probably what you're wanting. Windows file sharing (SMB or CIFS) has used encryption for authenticating to shared folders since at least Windows XP.

Comment: sorry if I misunderstand, but I was referring to my own local LAN activities, which are not part of the outside network. For example, I am accessing my bedroom PC from my living room PC and typing in my credentials. Would such activities be sent through the VPN server?